# special chars in rmail class

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, special-characters, typo3

I have a strange problem. I'm using the `rmail` class from Richard Heyes to send mails. This class works always as expected. Now I encountered a **strange problem** with **special chars**. Special chars were never a problem until now.

I have:

```
$this->mailEncoding = 'UTF-8';
$email->setHeadCharset($this->mailEncoding);
$email->setTextCharset($this->mailEncoding);
$email->setHTMLCharset($this->mailEncoding);
```

In this case the subject is a string like:

> ...ont été acceptée(s)

The subject is used as Mail-Subject (top) and then in content again

This is an image of the received mail in apple mail.
[image: This is an image of the received mail in apple mail.]

---

You see that the content is ok. In the subject été is ok too but acceptée(s) is not.
Now when I enter:

> ...ont été acceptétée(s)

I get (it works):

[image: This is an image of the received mail in apple mail.]

I tried several combinations. E.g **"à"** works. It seems that only **"ée"** is a problem

- The environment is **TYPO3**
- the strings are located in locallang_db.xml as **CDATA**
- I get them by **pi_getLL**

RAW:

```
00 : 56 6f 74 72 65 2f 76 6f 73 20 6d 61 6e 69 66 65 [Votre/vos manife]    
10 : 73 74 61 74 69 6f 6e 73 28 73 29 20 6f 6e 74 20 [stations(s) ont ]    
20 : c3 a9 74 c3 a9 20 61 63 63 65 70 74 c3 a9 65 28 [..t.. accept..e(]    
30 : 73 29 2e                                        [s).
```

Comment: You should give us a reproducible test case. For what I can see, the program that renders the message (Apple Mail) sees **two characters** (the double replacement character �) instead of just one (accept**é**e(s)), so there must be a program, somewhere in the chain, that is not fed with the encoding right for the input, and uses a single byte encoding (likely a code page, so maybe there's some Windows involved). May I ask where do you keep your messages and how you retrieve them?

Comment: Im sorry, its almost impossible to give you a reproducible test case. See above, I updated the question (TYPO3).
The thing with **two characters** I didn't notice. Strange.
Windows is nearly impossible. It's an iMac with MAMP :-)

Comment: Can you put `locallang_db.xml` on gist?

Comment: Also, it'd be helpful to see the raw email - I don't know Apple Mail, but all mail clients have kind of a "show source" feature that display the raw message, both headers and body

Comment: gist:https://gist.github.com/avarx/9760745

Comment: mail:upload.satzart.ch/uploadsatzart/mail.zip
Tell me if you downloaded it. i'll delete it afterwards.

Comment: Sorry, but the attached mail is rtf. We need to see the naked bytes going through the wire (some programs save the raw MIME envelope with the extension .eml, if it helps)

Comment: does this help?
mail:upload.satzart.ch/uploadsatzart/mail1.zip

Comment: Yes, it helps! Can you use a subject like `éeéeéeéeéeéeéeée` and send me the EML, too?

Comment: ok. i'll come back with this

Comment: It won't be enough, though. Please, read my answer below and try to attach any snippet of your code that transforms the text read from the translations file **and** provide a link to the sources of *rmail*

Comment: rmail:https://github.com/evpozdniakov/FW/tree/master/lib/Rmail

Comment: pi_getLL: http://doc-typo3.ameos.com/4.1.0/classtslib__pibase.html#9f1485184b49ba43be3b26a19cec2fde

Comment: $this->sendRmail(mailAsArray,$this->pi_getLL('EMAIL_VALIDATE_ORGANIZER_SUBJECT'),$mailcontent_text,$mailcontent_html);

Comment: Thanks for your help mate!! But I really can't post more. It's separated in x-Files (Model, View, Core). I would need to post my sendRmail Function the whole Rmail-Thing. The calls, the locallang. The TYPO3-Core Part (pi_getLL) etc...

Comment: I did a quick test with RMail, and it succeeded, hinting that the problem is on your part. It would be very helpful if you could set a breakpoint and provide a dump of the raw bytes that you pass to `$rmail->setSubject()` (or whatever it's called) - I know that the same message is used in the body, but the Rmail headers encoder, as per my test, has no problem with your input string

Comment: see RAW in my question. does this help?

Comment: If that's what you have just before sendind the bytes to Rmail, than it's likely to be Rmail's fault, because the message is correctly encoded in UTF-8. Try contacting the Rmail author and provide the the affected version and your code

Comment: i'll try another class to be sure its Rmail

Comment: you were right, it was Rmail. I now use https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.
Thanks mate!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [input file](https://gist.github.com/avarx/9760745) is valid UTF-8, but this is what your mail client reads:

```
...
Subject: [...] acceptÃ=?UTF-8?Q?=A9?=e.
...
```

Let's try to interpret your resource with different encodings:

```
Votre/vos manifestations(s) ont Ã©tÃ© acceptÃ©e(s). // CP-1252
Votre/vos manifestations(s) ont été acceptée(s).    // UTF-8
```

The `Ã` is written verbatim in the field body, while `U+00A9` is the code point for the [copyright symbol](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a9/index.htm). We can't tell for sure, but either you do something wrong with the string (can you check your code and attach any transformation?), or it may be a problem with the MIME message builder, which, as fare as I understand, is some *rmail* library (but I could not find it, so can't test against it)